# Unity stuck on the license screen

Tags: license, infinite-loop, unity3d

Whenever I open Unity it goes on the screen reactivate license and when active again it goes to the screen of choice between Pro and Personal and does not leave this screen, so I can not open the Unity editor! I searched the internet and tried the maximum of solutions, one worked, I changed the date of my computer for a day less and it worked, but after I closed and went to open again the same thing happened and it did not work anymore, I deleted the Unity folder which is inside the ProgramData but does not work. In the error log file there is this:

> *LICENSE SYSTEM [201923 18:7:4] Couldn't set permissions of the license file (Win32_AddFileAccessRights).
>
> *LICENSE SYSTEM [201923 18:7:4] License activated successfully with user: myemail@gmail.com
>
> *LICENSE SYSTEM [201923 18:7:4] Could not find digest XML element in license file. 
>   Exiting without the bug reporter. Application will terminate with return code 0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Unity you can easily do It by downloading the software in the official site. The Community version has lots of features and It's entirely free, without needing a license. I hope I understood your problem and helped you, if not please let me know It and post a picture of your issue.

Comment: I already have it installed, but I put the license it loads and says it's activating, but back to the manage licenses!